# Eigen elements manipulation without loop

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to check if the elements of my matrix are smaller than zero then I want to assign zero to them, in matlab it was done using this:

```
ind = find(floatFrame < 0);
floatFrame(ind) = 0;
```

Is there any equivalent for Eigen matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [select function](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#aaaed9ab0c7a20c689017542e40d1ef6e), which is similar to the ternary `?:` operator in C. For your example:

```
floatFrame = (floatFrame < 0).select(0, floatFrame)
```

Comment: Is it possible to perform this in-place?